# Trying To Wrap My Head Around Subversion Using Dreamweaver

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

I'm starting to work in a team environment on a website and I'm really wanting to start using some form of version control (I've also screwed my own work up, multiple times, without it).

I set up [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and created a repository using their recommendations (branches/tags/trunk).  I have the current version of a website in trunk/ and the redesign that I'm working on in branches.

When I first did my local copy, it put branches/tags/trunk mixed in with my local site directory.  I realized that I needed to create that whole repository cache as it would be on the server.  Now, I have branches/(redesign files), tags/(currently empty), and trunk/(public site files).  Now, commits and things look like they should.

I set up the remote server and the testing server, as normal.  But, now that I'm using the branches directory, whenever I put the files to the testing server, they are in a branches subdirectory (not what I want).

I could just have separate repositories, but my understanding is that it's better to have everything together.

Comment: So what are you asking exactly?

Comment: Yes, you need to have them in *one* repository to do merges. Do you need to `svn switch` your testing server to another directory?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very brief overview of the Subversion working pattern.

1. You set up the repository, with the three overarching folders, as described.
2. The **trunk** is where the latest "good" copy of work lives. Some people will do all or most of their committing to the trunk, if they are the only person working on things, and don't often have big changes. This is okay to start, but you will probably run into problems later when your needs get more complex.
3. The **branches** folder is where you store other folders that correspond to tasks or goals you have. If you are working on a redesign, then you would tell SVN, "Make a new branch called 'redesign' for me." It will create `branches/redesign` on the server, with all the same files as the trunk folder.
4. Since you want to work on those files, you have to *switch* to them, which tells Subversion "Take the files from `branches/redesign` and put them on my local machine, replacing what I've got now."
5. You work in Dreamweaver and *commit* your changes. They get pushed up to the server in the branches folder. You finish your redesign. Now you want to put your changes back in the trunk, so that future branches and commits see them (and anyone else you work with.) You do this by switching back to the trunk and **merging** your work. This tells Subversion "Take the files in `branches/redesign` and figure out how they differ from `trunk`, and apply those differences to the trunk." Then you check to make sure this happened correctly. Sometimes you will have conflicts if Subversion cannot figure this out automatically. You hand-correct those. Finally, you *commit* again.
6. At this point you could *delete* the branch, since you have merged and are done with it.
7. When you have everything ready (maybe after your redesign) and you deploy your site, you **tag** it to say "This is a new version, and I want to remember *exactly* what the files looked like, so I can go back and look at them if necessary." A tag is like a snapshot of your files, frozen in time forever.

Comment: It sounds like the main Subversion work is actually being done OUTSIDE of Dreamweaver (switch, merge, tag).  I'm assuming that's where the command-line version or TortoiseSVN would come into play.  I've been looking at my options in VisualSVN Server and I don't see any of those.  Given that Dreamweaver uses Subversion 1.6.9 and TortoiseSVN is using 1.7.x, do I need to install an older version of TortoiseSVN?  One obvious difference is that I have .svn in EVERY directory (boy is that annoying).

Comment: As far as I know, the newer client will connect to an older server fine, so TortoiseSVN should be able to cope. I'm not familiar with Dreamweaver's built-in client.

Comment: I wasn't referring to an older server.  My server is 1.7.8, but Dreamweaver's client is 1.6.9.  The current build of TortoiseSVN is 1.7.11 (I think).  So, I would have two clients, on the same machine, using the same working copy, that are different minor versions.  From what I've read, a newer version of TortoiseSVN would break compatibility with Dreamweaver.  There are 1.6.x versions of TortoiseSVN.  I was just wondering if an older version would be preferable to a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the "correct" way of working with Subversion, testing servers, etc... in Dreamweaver, but it does seem to work the way I anticipate.

Instead of accessing the whole repository, I'm just accessing the branches subdirectory of the repository.  As such, my local copy doesn't have branches, tags, or trunk.  With that, Put to my testing server functions as expected.

At this point, I would need to do tags, merge with trunk, etc... on the Subversion server (as opposed to Dreamweaver).  I'm thinking that is probably a better way of doing it, anyway.

Does all of this sound normal?  I've never really worked with version control, before (I'm reading through the SVN Book), so I'm not sure of the "correct" way of doing everything.  My effort is to use the built-in functionality of Dreamweaver, as this team will be using it and I don't want to overly-complicate the process.  I will probably end up being the version control administrator and myself and others will be doing the daily website maintenance.